# IE needs to run as Admin just to save file or create folder from Silverlight App

Tags: internet-explorer, silverlight-5.0

I have this Silverligth 5 application that cater MS Word add, edit and save to database in server. Editing the word file requires downloading it from server and save to local drive in %userprofile%\AppData\TheFolder (TheFolder is programmatically created once the application run). The problem is that, even in trusted configured app (in browser; added the site in IE trusted zone, signed the XAP, added registry key and elevate the app) the user (client side) needs to open the IE "run as administrator" to enable full access to this folder and able to save a copy of MS Word. The purpose of a local copy is that, once the upload fails for three times, it can still recover his/her work and later try to edit and upload it again.

How can we avoid to open IE "run as admin". Please help

Comment: What EXACTLY happens in the failing scenario? Showing a trace from SysInternals' Process Monitor would be helpful.

Comment: It says, it has no permission to create the folder